# How does looping though a PHP array using While() work?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have found some PHP code that connects to a MySQL database and gets the column `CityName` for each row of the table `Cities`. I'm curious why `while()` loop is used and not `for()` or `foreach`. So here are my questions regarding how `while()` works in case of looping through arrays:

- First, isn't `$row` variable an 2D array which it's rows contains the list of cities from the SQL query and it's columns contain the columns of each row of the query?
- If this is the case, couldn't `for()` or `foreach()` be used to loop through the `$row` array?
- Second, how does `while()` know when the array ends using only `$row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()` in the `while()`'s first line in order to end the loop?
- Third, how does `while()` move to the next row of the `$row` array without using `next()` at the end of the loop?
- And last but not least, how does `echo $row['CityName'];` output the city name of each row of the `$row` array without specifying the row of the array to use but only it's column `CityName`?

Thanks for any answers.

```
$query="SELECT CityName FROM Cities";

if($stmt = $connection->query("$query"))
{

  while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) 
  {   
    echo $row['CityName'];
  }

}
else
{
  echo $connection->error;
}
```

Comment: One................ question at at time. What you posted, is too broad.

Comment: $row is 1D array = 1 row.

Comment: *while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc())* is eq. of: *while (true) { $row = $stmt->fetch_assoc(); if (!$row) break; ...*

Comment: 1) no. 1.b) it could, but doesn't apply here. 2) when `fetch_assoc()` returns NULL (meaning no more results to fetch), that is cast to false which makes the loop end. 3) that's what *loops* do at the end of their block - they *loop* back. 4) $row is just *one* row of the result... i would suggest you go and learn some basics about how computer programs work.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`. Also avoid anti-patterns like `"$x"` where `$x` alone is equivalent.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Your comment was very helpful to me (I have never used `while()` before in this way) so why didn't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @tadman Where did I use `"$x"` in my code?

Comment: The `"$query"` in your code. I'm using `$x` as a generic version of same. That shouldn't be in quotes, and additionally, that throw-away single-use variable shouldn't exist, just but the query where `$query` is. It's way harder to "mis-fire" a query that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop through $row, because it is an array (a simple array, not a 2d array); but you're not looping through an array called $row with the `while`, you're iterating over the resultset returned by `$stmt->fetch_assoc()` - which isn't an array- and assigning the value of a single returned row to `$row` in that statement (note the `=` for assignment) from the resultset.

`while` itself doesn't magically move any pointer; it's the call to `$stmt->fetch_assoc()` that not only returns a single row result, but moves the resultset pointer to the next result (and determines when it has reached the end of the resultset)

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($this_is_true){
// do this
}
# if the condition is not true for this while stmt, it will not execute (not even once)

do{ 
 // stuff here 
} while($thisIsTrue);
# even if the condition isn't true, a do-while executes at least once (the first time)
```

The point is that they are using a while() because it's a lazy way to say "only do it if it's true", so they don't have to check if it's true before they loop through it. WIth a for loop, you need to know the number of results you are looping through. For a do, you need to know that there are results before you attempt to use the results (echo). So, you use a while() to check if it's valid and then execute it, with just that piece of code.

Personally, I like to do...

```
if($query->num_rows > 0){
 $query->bind_result($bindvar);
 while($query->fetch()){
  // do stuff
 }
 $query->close();
} else {
 // no results found 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` instead of `while`. At least if `stmt` is a [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) and you PHP version is not terribly outdated (newer than 5.4). In that case your loop would be:

```
foreach($stmt as $row) 
{   
  echo $row['CityName'];
}
```

**But** this does not mean that `$stmt` is a 2D array. It's an object that implements the Traversable interface. That means that the foreach loop will implicitly invoke the required methods.